# User not updating in mongo after save?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an app for todos. I'm trying to update a specific todo within an array of todos stored in the User I'm currently logged into. This is the code that does that:

```
User.findById(req.user._id)
        .then(user => {
            user.todos.forEach(function(todo) {
                if (todo._id == req.params.todoId) {
                    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
                    console.log(todo.completed);
                }
            })
            return user.save();
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            res.json(result);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            res.send(err);
        })
```

When I console.log the result, everything comes out fine. When I console log the updated Todo in the ajax call I'm making in my javascript file, everything appears fine. The todo is updated. However, when I stop my server and find the user in Mongo, the todo still isn't updated.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you modify a nested property on a document, mongoose may not be aware that anything changed, so it won't know to persist the changes in the DB (otherwise it would have to pass everything, which could become expensive if you have a large document but only a tiny part of it changed).

This can be done via the [`markModified`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified) method:

```
 user.todos.forEach(function(todo) {
   if (todo._id == req.params.todoId) {
     todo.completed = !todo.completed;
     console.log(todo.completed);
   }
 })
 user.markModified('todos');
 return user.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it in JavaScript code I will suggest you can do it in query only which will more effective.

```
db.getCollection('User').update({"_id":<req.user._id>,"todo._id":<req.params.todoId>},
 {$set: 
     {'todo.$.completed': true}
 }, {
   new : true
 }
)
```

In this query you need to pass completed status as well.